# Google Play quests

Tags: google-play-games

In [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests), can I define a quest that require multiple events to be accord in order to get the reword?

The Completion Criteria description says:

> How Play Games determines if the quest is completed. This consists of
>   an event (which you can enter by name), and the number of times the
>   event must occur to complete this criteria (for example, “Kill Zombie”
>   100 times).

It sounds like it's not possible, but it's not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests
"In the quest definition, specify the events that represent player actions or milestones needed to complete the quest."
That made me think it's possible... but:

The Quest object has a method called getCurrentMilestone()
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quest.html#getCurrentMilestone()

The Milestone class only has information for a single event.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Milestone.html

So I think the answer is no.